# Session is UNDEFINED after redirecting to another page in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, session, express

What I am trying to do is

-> use a logic form which posts to '/check_user'

-> check_user has logic to generate session and it creates the session perfectly

-> then it redirects to '/chat' which is restricted by verify() function

-> verify checks the session if persists (**AT THIS POINT SESSION IS ALWAYS UNDEFINED FOR SOME REASON)**

--> check_user does create session and it persists there but when redirected to '/chat' and hits verify, the session is lost.

Here is the code snippet I am using, I am not using any templating engines but plain HTML files. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get('/chat', verify, function(req, res){
 res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/chat.html');
});


// when login form is posted to check_user, handle the username and passwords validation.
  app.post('/check_user', function(req, res){

  req.session.regenerate(function(){
    req.session.user = "test";

    //debugging codes debug code 1
    console.log("3");
    console.log(req.session.user);
    //End debugging codes

    res.redirect('/chat');
  });

});
```

function verify(req, res, next) {

```
  console.log(req.session.user);

  if (req.session.user) {

      console.log("1");//debug code 2

    next();

  } else {

      console.log("2");//debug code 3

    req.session.error = 'Access denied!';

    res.redirect('/login');

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! it. The problem was I was using res.render after ajax submit. I used window.location on ajax submit and it worked.

And another thing I found out is,
removing this closure made my session persistant throughout my application

req.session.regenerate(function(){

});